# How do I backup within elementary OS?

Tags: gnome, backup

For past 1 year, I've been working on elementary OS and due to instability and other issues in the OS, i am switching from elementary OS to gnome ubuntu which is also a debian OS. my question is if i backup my data on elementary OS, can i backup the same on gnome ubuntu? is it possible that all my installations are easily available back on the gnome ubuntu?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about elementary OS

Comment: But why? It's about elementary only

Comment: Are you trying to switch to GNOME or elementary OS ?

Comment: GNome and I need complete backup from elementary and there is no backup option in settings

Comment: Press CTRL + H while the home folder is open in files.You should see hidden files appear.Then press CTRL + A to select all and then CTRL + C to copy and use CTRL + V to paste them on to your backup folder / drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Aptik Migration Utility](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/aptik.html).

To install it:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa 
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install aptik
```